# Best way to manually update package

Tags: package-management, updates, ppa

I am using Texstudio, version 2.9.4. While this is the latest available from the ppa ([here](https://launchpad.net/~blahota/+archive/ubuntu/texstudio/)), there is a new stable version available. Since apt-get won't see this update, I need to install it manually. Do I just download the deb file and install it on top of the existing version (this is, will the new version recognize the old one and only update it), or do I uninstall the current one, and install from scratch? I think my question relates to the actual nature of the "apt-get update" command, which I think I want to mimic.

Answer (score 1):

The question here goes back to whether Texstudio provides a `.deb` and whether it is identical to the one in the PPA.

If the package names match up exactly, then you *might* be able to download the `.deb` from Texstudio and install on top of the existing (essentially, 'updating' the package manually) by using `dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb` (replacing the path accordingly).  This will 'override' the installed version, but it does not exactly replicate what `apt-get update` does, which is check repository servers for updates to download.

Comment: They do provide a .deb file, and it seems the names are the same (I don't see why they should not be). But then, what does update do if not install the full version? I have never seen "patches" on repositories.

Comment: @luchonacho 'Patches' are just changes to the software.  In repositories and Debian packages, they're applied, and new Debian packages get generated.  `apt-get update` is an automated 'update' process that reaches out to repository servers for newer versions of packages, and then `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade packages if newer versions exist.  But `apt-get` does not work with downloaded `.deb` files you're trying to install manually (though it can resolve dependencies after the fact)  That's what the `dpkg -i` command is for